# Created the formula but now have to break it up into years; there is a years column in original data seat with header for years

Tags: mysql-workbench, formula, absolute, year2038

As title suggests, I created a result with a formula but now need to break it up into having the formula run for every "owner" but seperate the formula into years. I have the dates 2010-2019. Here is the code

SELECT * FROM finaltab;

Select finaltab.OWNER as OWNER, SUM(finaltab.shares) AS SSUM FROM finaltab WHERE trancode='S' GROUP BY OWNER Order by year;
Select finaltab.OWNER as OWNER, SUM(finaltab.shares) AS PSUM FROM finaltab WHERE trancode='P' GROUP BY OWNER Order by year;

SELECT finaltab.OWNER, SSUM, PSUM FROM
(SELECT finaltab.OWNER AS OWNER, SUM(finaltab.shares) AS SSUM FROM finaltab WHERE trancode='S' GROUP BY OWNER) AS STable
INNER JOIN
(SELECT finaltab.OWNER AS OWNER, SUM(finaltab.shares) AS PSUM FROM finaltab WHERE trancode='P' GROUP BY OWNER) aS PTable
ON (Stable.owner = Ptable.owner);

SELECT STable.OWNER, SSUM, PSUM, (PSUM - SSUM) / (PSUM + SSUM) as "IOF" FROM
(SELECT finaltab.OWNER as OWNER, SUM(finaltab.shares) AS SSUM From finaltab WHERE trancode='S' GROUP BY OWNER) AS STable
INNER JOIN
(SELECT finaltab.OWNER as OWNER, SUM(finaltab.shares) AS PSUM From finaltab WHERE trancode='P' GROUP BY OWNER) AS PTable
ON (STable.OWNER = PTable.OWNER);

Here is the table. Also I would like some direction on if I want to take the "IOF" or formula and implement it into a formula with absolute value for the "IOF" in the numerator. Thank you [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9GtU.png

Comment: Don't you just need to add `year` to the `group by`? (And return year in the results.)

Comment: how is this done in regard to my code? Can I add another group by when refering to another column?

Comment: `group by column1, column2`